# C# Populate ObjectB field by operating on its parent without type checking

Tags: c#, oop

Object X has some data that Object B is interested in but it operates on its parent (Object A). Object B declares a field that isn't declared in object A. Object C is also a child of Object A but it doesn't declare that field that object B does.

How to populate object B field? (is type checking and casting really the only solution?)

EDIT (Added an example)

```
public class ObjectX
{
    // eventually interested by ObjectB
    public float time;
    
    private ObjectA _objectAOrBStoredInAReference;

    public ObjectX(ObjectA objectAOrB)
    {
        this._objectAOrBStoredInAReference = objectAOrB;
    }

    public void PassTimeToObjectB()
    {
        // need to pass the time to ObjectB since it is interested in this
    }

    public void SomeStuffToDo()
    {
        PassTimeToObjectB();
        _objectAOrBStoredInAReference.StuffToDo();
    }

    public abstract class ObjectA
    {
        public abstract void StuffToDo();
    }
    
    public class ObjectB : ObjectA
    {
        public float time;

        public void SetTime(float time)
        {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public override void StuffToDo()
        {
            // Using Populated time here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to see code of what you have (simplified), and what you want to do.  It is easier than reading text which is so abstracted.

Comment: Please provide the example with code

Comment: It sounds like you are violating [Liskov](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle) here - if `X` requires the property defined on `B`, why does `X` accept an `A`? Why don't you restrict it to accept a `B`? What would happen if you passed a `C` to `X`? Would it be a runtime error or could it do something useful with it? This question needs more context, and a code sample :)

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I've added an example :)

Comment: "is type checking..." - when apparently you have an object that could be of different types and you want to make decisions based on the specific type, why would you think that type checking *wasn't* part of the answer?

Comment: I don't like the type checking since its kinda of a code smell and I'm not sure how this would affect my future design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of solutions here:

### 1: Only `ObjectX` knows the time

If the `time` is such that only `ObjectX` can possibly know it, then you can pass `ObjectX` as an argument to `StuffToDo`:

```
public class ObjectX
{
    // eventually interested by ObjectB
    private float time;

    // Expose 'time' as a readonly property - I'm assuming
    // other classes shouldn't need to manipulate it?
    public float Time => time;

    private ObjectA _objectAOrBStoredInAReference;

    public ObjectX(ObjectA objectAOrB)
    {
        this._objectAOrBStoredInAReference = objectAOrB;
    }

    public void SomeStuffToDo()
    {
        // Don't need to set the time anymore - 
        // ObjectB can retrieve the time itself.
        _objectAOrBStoredInAReference.StuffToDo(this);
    }
}

public class ObjectB : ObjectA
{
    // REMOVE ALL THIS CODE - NOT NEEDED ANYMORE
    //public float time;

    //public void SetTime(float time)
    //{
    //   this.time = time;
    //}

    public override void StuffToDo(ObjectX x)
    {
        var time = x.Time;
        // Do stuff involving 'time'.
    }
}
```

### 2: The time can be known solution-wide:

If the time is just a general time that is not specific to `ObjectX` then expose it via it's own type `ITimeProvider`:

```
public interface ITimeProvider
{
    float Time { get;}
}

public class ObjectX
{
    // Remove any 'time' related stuff from X
    private ObjectA _objectAOrBStoredInAReference;

    public ObjectX(ObjectA objectAOrB)
    {
        this._objectAOrBStoredInAReference = objectAOrB;
    }

    public void SomeStuffToDo()
    {
        _objectAOrBStoredInAReference.StuffToDo();
    }
}

public class ObjectB : ObjectA
{
    private readonly ITimeProvider _timeProvider;
    public ObjectB(ITimeProvider timeProvider)
    {
        this._timeProvider = timeProvider;
    }
 
    public override void StuffToDo(ObjectX x)
    {
        var time = _timeProvider.Time;
        // Do stuff involving 'time'.
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, it helped a lot. Thanks!